# Regular Expressions: Remove x-leading spaces from lines

Tags: regex

To remove, e.g. (exactly) 2 leading spaces from each line, I've tried to replace

```
"^  "
```

with

```
""
```

I tried that with our own text editor and with Notepad++. Both behave the same and start the search at the same position where the last found/replace happend, so it will actually remove 2n spaces from each line (n >= 0). Is this the expected behavior? Is my used regular expression wrong for that task or do our own text editor and Notepad++ behave incorrectly?

Comment: You seem to be asking if it is correct that `"^  "` regex removes `n` times double spaces from the start of each line. It is expected behavior in Notepad++. If you only need to remove the first two, use `"^  (.*)"` and replace with `$1`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue here is that Notepad++ will keep replacing a pattern so long as it keeps finding matches.  This means that replacing `^` will keep stripping whitespace from the start of the string, so long as there are two or more leading spaces available.

Try this as a workaround:

**Find:**

```
^  (.*)$
```

**Replace:**

```
$1
```